# Is using a variable key with constant data as secure as using a constant key with variable data which signing uri's with hash_hmac() in PHP

Tags: php, security, encryption

The theory is that typically we create signed URI's like

```
$superSecret = 'abc';
$data = 'https://localhost/verify/{user-id}/{email}';
$hash = hash_hmac('sha256', $data, $superSecret);

$uri = $data . '/?hash=' . $hash;
```

Then we can validate the signature by recreating a hash, and calling `hash_equals()`. If any of part of the data string changed, `hash_equal()` returns false.

What happens if we switch some parameters around. This time instead of hashing different data, we hash the same data every time but with different keys.

I.e.

```
$superSecret = 'abc' . $userId . $email;
$data = 'https://localhost/verify';
$hash = hash_hmac('sha256', $data, $superSecret);

$uri  = $data;
```

The above are dumbed down generalized examples. But I'm more interested in, is the concept correct? Would using different keys to hash the same data be as secure as using different data hashed by the same key.

Comment: If someone can derive the secret from something else, e.g. because it’s their user id which they know, then they can spoof HMACs with it. That’s why the `$superSecret` should be *super secret*.

Comment: and it is.. i'm just adding to the `$superSecret` not replacing it

Comment: Then it probably doesn’t add much to add information to the secret which can be derived. It may seem like it makes the secret “better” if it’s different for every user, but if the user can know the added data, it’s essentially meaningless. There *may* or may not be a cryptographic weakness introduced by adding predictable information, I do not know; but even without knowing that, I’d say it doesn’t substantially *improve* anything either.

Comment: What you're saying makes sense. But i'm not trying to improve on the hash_hmac functionality.. My interests are in the `$uri` in the above examples.. As the "abc" in `$superSecret` is never exposed, is signing the same URI at a disadvantage as signing a dynamic URI.. Regardless of which method is used, `$user-id` and `$email` are always user provided and "abc" of `$secret` is always secure..

Comment: So, essentially you’re rotating the secret, which can’t be a bad thing; except if the rotation is predictable in some way (this is), and on top of that if the predictable component may introduce a cryptographic weakness (again, don’t know). Over at http://security.stackexchange.com you will find more people able to elaborate on the latter part.

Comment: "on top of that if the predictable component may introduce a cryptographic weakness (again, don’t know)." @deceze that's what I'm trying to find out. haha as part of the secret is unknown and part of it is, whats the difference in using the known part in the data vs half the secret.. Didn't even think of http://security.stackexchange.com/ thanks for that